# how to do string comparison on C LPWSTR?

Tags: c, visual-c++

In Visual C 2010 how do you do a string comparison to check for equality between a char* and a LPWSTR? For example, do something to the extent of

```
LPWSTR *str; 
if (*str == "fileName") //...
```

Comment: Try `(wsccmp(str, L"fileName") == 0)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the wsccmp function should do what you are looking to do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731(v=vs.80).aspx